# Find Duplicate Records Whose CreateDate are Off by a Time-Interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Somehow, duplicate documents are getting created in the database.  But...before I can look at HOW they are getting created...I need to understand how VAST the issue is (or isn't).  Below is a screen shot of my starting-point

- 3 Documents got created (for the same GlobalId) within milliseconds of each other
- I want to COMPARE DocumentCreateDate's (within an INTERVAL) across a related-series of GROUPING's
- The goal would be to get a list of DocumentId's whose interval is LESS THAN something (say 5 minutes)

[image]

- I know I need to do this recursively
- I know I am getting closer & closer

...can someone help me finish this?

**MY CURRENT SQL:**

```
;WITH CTE_All_Documents AS
(SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY DocumentId, EntityDefaultSearchTerm) AS RowNumber
    , COUNT(participation.DocumentId) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm) AS SubTotal
    , participation.DocumentId
    , participation.EntityDefaultSearchTerm
FROM [dbo].[vDocumentParticipation] participation
WHERE
    participation.EntityCategory = 'Device'
    AND participation.DocumentTypeShortName = 'SCADA'
GROUP BY
    participation.DocumentId
    , participation.EntityDefaultSearchTerm)

SELECT
    RowNumber
    , SubTotal
    , DocumentId
    , EntityDefaultSearchTerm
    , document.CreateDate
FROM CTE_All_Documents orderedDocuments 
JOIN [dbo].[Document] document ON document.Id = orderedDocuments.DocumentId
WHERE 
    SubTotal > 1
    --AND EntityDefaultSearchTerm = 'Jackdaw 2-10H'
```

[image]

**TEST DATA:** 
In case this helps, I tried to create a quick set of test-data...

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (DocumentId INT, EntityDefaultSearchTerm VARCHAR(100), CreateDate DATETIME2(7))


INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5481, '093-80126', CAST('2020-11-10T07:18:03.8766667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 9487, '093-80126', CAST('2021-09-17T09:21:45.9733333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 9488, '093-80126', CAST('2021-09-17T09:48:57.8766667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5177, '094-60069', CAST('2020-10-07T12:50:09.5700000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5178, '094-60069', CAST('2020-10-07T12:50:11.2566667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5179, '094-60069', CAST('2020-10-07T12:50:12.5700000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5180, '094-60069', CAST('2020-10-07T12:50:13.5400000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5615, '095-07365', CAST('2020-11-18T10:21:44.1400000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6818, '095-07365', CAST('2021-04-22T08:58:37.6233333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 10782, '095-07365', CAST('2021-10-08T08:18:25.5766667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5769, '099-8014BEN', CAST('2020-11-30T10:51:27.0900000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 9257, '099-8014BEN', CAST('2021-09-01T10:23:39.4333333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 9270, '099-8014BEN', CAST('2021-09-01T10:52:10.2466667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7535, '107759', CAST('2021-06-21T15:36:38.5933333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7568, '107759', CAST('2021-06-25T08:01:08.1133333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7616, '107759', CAST('2021-06-30T08:01:30.5566667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6500, '90879', CAST('2021-03-14T21:03:49.0933333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8118, '90879', CAST('2021-08-23T08:03:22.8933333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8123, '90879', CAST('2021-08-23T14:15:22.8633333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6700, '930930018 SITTER B', CAST('2021-04-07T15:23:30.2133333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6926, '930930018 SITTER B', CAST('2021-05-03T14:41:38.4833333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6927, '930930018 SITTER B', CAST('2021-05-03T14:41:38.9700000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6431, '98120601', CAST('2021-03-04T10:37:20.6533333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6904, '98120601', CAST('2021-04-29T13:38:02.6300000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6905, '98120601', CAST('2021-04-29T13:38:03.4733333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6906, '98120601', CAST('2021-04-29T13:38:04.2333333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6182, 'ButterFinger', CAST('2021-01-26T14:27:43.6366667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6936, 'ButterFinger', CAST('2021-05-04T10:07:44.1300000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7869, 'ButterFinger', CAST('2021-07-29T11:40:09.7000000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6183, 'Butterfinger 22-1HGL', CAST('2021-01-26T14:35:34.0966667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6937, 'Butterfinger 22-1HGL', CAST('2021-05-04T10:12:42.9800000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7870, 'Butterfinger 22-1HGL', CAST('2021-07-29T11:42:40'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6117, 'Champion 334', CAST('2021-01-18T12:20:40.9833333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6118, 'Champion 334', CAST('2021-01-18T12:20:41.9166667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 10804, 'Champion 334', CAST('2021-10-11T12:21:02.7500000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 4824, 'EDITH JACKSON 2', CAST('2020-09-03T15:14:10.5133333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5601, 'EDITH JACKSON 2', CAST('2020-11-18T09:54:57.9166667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7574, 'EDITH JACKSON 2', CAST('2021-06-28T09:00:23.2033333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6350, 'Gibbs CDP', CAST('2021-02-23T08:04:00.1433333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6351, 'Gibbs CDP', CAST('2021-02-23T08:11:06.6066667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6352, 'Gibbs CDP', CAST('2021-02-23T08:16:57.6000000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5517, 'Isaacs B-191-4', CAST('2020-11-11T13:39:07.0233333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6489, 'Isaacs B-191-4', CAST('2021-03-11T11:28:55.4500000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7375, 'Isaacs B-191-4', CAST('2021-06-07T11:57:43.4733333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 11003, 'Jackdaw 2-10H', CAST('2021-10-28T08:01:30.4633333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 11004, 'Jackdaw 2-10H', CAST('2021-10-28T08:01:30.6366667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 11005, 'Jackdaw 2-10H', CAST('2021-10-28T08:01:32.9300000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 3923, 'MARSHALL DILLON 25 #1 SALES', CAST('2020-05-21T10:18:33.2733333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 3925, 'MARSHALL DILLON 25 #1 SALES', CAST('2020-05-21T10:49:02.1200000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 4298, 'MARSHALL DILLON 25 #1 SALES', CAST('2020-07-01T09:21:23.9200000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5535, 'MOORE 12-1', CAST('2020-11-12T14:22:18.1200000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6991, 'MOORE 12-1', CAST('2021-05-06T12:33:24.3533333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 10744, 'MOORE 12-1', CAST('2021-10-06T13:04:16.8833333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5605, 'NORTH PT LAVACA LOOP CG', CAST('2020-11-18T10:02:23.4900000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6923, 'NORTH PT LAVACA LOOP CG', CAST('2021-05-03T12:40:16.6800000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8010, 'NORTH PT LAVACA LOOP CG', CAST('2021-08-09T15:24:11.8233333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 4985, 'PARSELL, WARREN B F-7', CAST('2020-09-24T14:40:53.3766667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6471, 'PARSELL, WARREN B F-7', CAST('2021-03-08T12:25:08.3933333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8164, 'PARSELL, WARREN B F-7', CAST('2021-08-25T11:37:05.4366667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5389, 'PHP Waha Oasis', CAST('2020-10-28T08:00:46.0666667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5471, 'PHP Waha Oasis', CAST('2020-11-06T10:04:12.6900000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5508, 'PHP Waha Oasis', CAST('2020-11-11T09:15:44.1333333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7497, 'PHP Waha Oasis', CAST('2021-06-16T13:29:31.3466667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6440, 'Rigs Star West', CAST('2021-03-04T14:14:05.2033333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6505, 'Rigs Star West', CAST('2021-03-16T12:44:07.1700000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7920, 'Rigs Star West', CAST('2021-07-30T14:26:31.4533333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 5297, 'Shelton North Offload ', CAST('2020-10-15T07:54:51.3366667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6629, 'Shelton North Offload ', CAST('2021-03-31T10:34:01.4200000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6705, 'Shelton North Offload ', CAST('2021-04-08T11:13:58.7900000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6329, 'Spider Enterprice IC', CAST('2021-02-12T10:48:04.4300000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6335, 'Spider Enterprice IC', CAST('2021-02-16T12:41:03.2366667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 6484, 'Spider Enterprice IC', CAST('2021-03-10T14:43:01.0966667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8042, 'stn-050226', CAST('2021-08-14T21:24:05.7266667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8043, 'stn-050226', CAST('2021-08-14T21:24:09.0233333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8044, 'stn-050226', CAST('2021-08-14T21:24:09.8833333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7394, 'stn-091-45018', CAST('2021-06-09T08:17:29.9233333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7998, 'stn-091-45018', CAST('2021-08-09T11:18:53.4900000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 8030, 'stn-091-45018', CAST('2021-08-12T10:24:27.1033333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 4370, 'stn-093-08280', CAST('2020-07-08T12:24:50.0733333'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 4371, 'stn-093-08280', CAST('2020-07-08T12:29:30.8100000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 4372, 'stn-093-08280', CAST('2020-07-08T12:38:41.2966667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7288, 'stn-095-70565', CAST('2021-05-28T08:46:07.9700000'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 7739, 'stn-095-70565', CAST('2021-07-15T13:17:59.4066667'AS DATETIME2(7))
INSERT INTO @TestData SELECT 9534, 'stn-095-70565', CAST('2021-09-20T13:57:54.3200000'AS DATETIME2(7))


SELECT * FROM @TestData
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()` to show all records that have a `CreateDate` within 5 minutes (or whatever interval you like) of a neighboring record:

```sql
with delta as (
    select *
          ,prevDt =  lag(CreateDate) over (partition by EntityDefaultSearchTerm order by CreateDate)
          ,nextDt = lead(CreateDate) over (partition by EntityDefaultSearchTerm order by CreateDate)
    from @TestData
)
select DocumentId, EntityDefaultSearchTerm, CreateDate
from delta
     cross apply (values (5 * 60)) span(sec)
where datediff(second,prevDt    ,CreateDate) <= span.sec
   or datediff(second,CreateDate,nextDt    ) <= span.sec
order by EntityDefaultSearchTerm,CreateDate
;
```

Results from your test data set:

```
| DocumentId | EntityDefaultSearchTerm | CreateDate                  |
+------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
|       5177 | 094-60069               | 2020-10-07 12:50:09.5700000 |
|       5178 | 094-60069               | 2020-10-07 12:50:11.2566667 |
|       5179 | 094-60069               | 2020-10-07 12:50:12.5700000 |
|       5180 | 094-60069               | 2020-10-07 12:50:13.5400000 |
|       6926 | 930930018 SITTER B      | 2021-05-03 14:41:38.4833333 |
|       6927 | 930930018 SITTER B      | 2021-05-03 14:41:38.9700000 |
|       6904 | 98120601                | 2021-04-29 13:38:02.6300000 |
|       6905 | 98120601                | 2021-04-29 13:38:03.4733333 |
|       6906 | 98120601                | 2021-04-29 13:38:04.2333333 |
|       6117 | Champion 334            | 2021-01-18 12:20:40.9833333 |
|       6118 | Champion 334            | 2021-01-18 12:20:41.9166667 |
|      11003 | Jackdaw 2-10H           | 2021-10-28 08:01:30.4633333 |
|      11004 | Jackdaw 2-10H           | 2021-10-28 08:01:30.6366667 |
|      11005 | Jackdaw 2-10H           | 2021-10-28 08:01:32.9300000 |
|      11019 | Jackdaw 2-10H           | 2021-10-28 08:06:25.6700000 | <-- the extra one
|       8042 | stn-050226              | 2021-08-14 21:24:05.7266667 |
|       8043 | stn-050226              | 2021-08-14 21:24:09.0233333 |
|       8044 | stn-050226              | 2021-08-14 21:24:09.8833333 |
|       4370 | stn-093-08280           | 2020-07-08 12:24:50.0733333 |
|       4371 | stn-093-08280           | 2020-07-08 12:29:30.8100000 |
```

NOTE: I threw in an extra "Jackdaw 2-10H" to illustrate that the notion of a group of records is somewhat ambiguous.  With the addition of document 11019, document 11005 belongs to two groups:

- 11003 through 11005
- 11005 through 11019

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your request, and the following code helps.
Try this:

```
DECLARE @MaxTargetOffset    int =   5 * 60 -- 5 minutes by 60 seconds. comparison will be in seconds)
;
WITH    EntityCTE1  AS
    (
            SELECT 
                    RowNumber   =   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY DocumentId, EntityDefaultSearchTerm)
                ,   * 
            FROM @TestData
    )
    ,   EntityCTE2  AS  
    (
            SELECT 
                    RowNumber   =   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY DocumentId, EntityDefaultSearchTerm)
                ,   * 
            FROM @TestData
    )
    , EntityOffset  AS
    (
        SELECT  
                DocumentId1 =   E1.DocumentId
            ,   DocumentId2 =   E2.DocumentId
            ,   EntityName  =   E1.EntityDefaultSearchTerm
            ,   CreateDate  =   E1.CreateDate
            ,   TimeOffset  =   DATEDIFF(second, E1.CreateDate, E2.CreateDate)
        FROM    EntityCTE1  E1
        JOIN    EntityCTE2  E2  ON  E2.EntityDefaultSearchTerm      =   E1.EntityDefaultSearchTerm
                                AND CONVERT(date, E2.CreateDate)    =   CONVERT(date, E1.CreateDate)
        WHERE   E1.RowNumber    <   E2.RowNumber
    )

SELECT *
FROM EntityOffset
WHERE   TimeOffset > = @MaxTargetOffset
ORDER BY EntityName, DocumentId1
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions, here is one simple solution, if not very performant over large datasets.

- Use `LAG` to identify starting points for each group
- Use a running conditional count to assign each group an ID
- Run more window functions or grouping functions over that ID

```sql
DECLARE @diffSeconds int = 1;

WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart =
          CASE WHEN CreateDate >
               DATEADD(second, @diffSeconds,
                   LAG(CreateDate, 1, '19000101') OVER (PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY CreateDate))
               THEN 1 END
    FROM @TestData td
),
Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY CreateDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM StartPoints td
),
PerGroup AS (
    SELECT *,
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm, GroupId ORDER BY CreateDate),
      SubTotal = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm, GroupId)
    FROM Groups
)
SELECT
  SubTotal,
  RowNumber,
  DocumentId,
  EntityDefaultSearchTerm,
  CreateDate
FROM PerGroup td
WHERE SubTotal > 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d75645611d6e0f65bbb1b424571b714b)

You can substantially reduce runtime on large datasets by using normal aggregation in the later stages, instead of window functions.

There are also solutions involving just `LEAD` and `LAG`, however they can be fairly complex.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close, you just need to fix the `OVER` clause to be :

```
OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY CreateDate)
```

Which would give you the desired groupings.

Now, for the comparing dates, you will need to use `LEAD` or `LAG` windowed functions (with the same `OVER` clause) to get the next or previous date, and apply `DATEDIFF` function on it to get the interval difference between them. The rest will be at your hands.

Here is a quick example :

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY CreateDate) RN 
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm) AS DuplicatesCount
    , ISNULL(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreateDate, LEAD(CreateDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY CreateDate)), 0) Seconds_Diff
    , ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CreateDate, LEAD(CreateDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY CreateDate)), 0) Minutes_Diff 
    , ISNULL(DATEDIFF(HOUR, CreateDate, LEAD(CreateDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EntityDefaultSearchTerm ORDER BY CreateDate)), 0) Hour_Diff
    FROM @TestData
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE 
    DuplicatesCount > 1 -- only get duplicates
AND YEAR(CreateDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) -- only get current year records
AND Hour_Diff = 0 -- same hour
AND Minutes_Diff = 0 -- same minute 
AND Seconds_Diff > 0 -- different seconds which could be the case you are working on.
```